# Custom Port not working for node.js app on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed the following code on my AWS EC2 instance -

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/test',(req,res) => {res.send('Hi')})

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Server running on port 80'))
```

When I try to visit the following url - http://ec2-13-59-209-0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test  , I get connection refused message. The message on the UI is ec2-13-59-209-0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.

I did go through the documentation and set up security group to listen on port 3001. But that did not help either.So I enabled on traffic for all the ports. Still I was not able to connect. Please find below snapshot of the security group. It would be great if you can help me with this.

[image]

Comment: By Default it runs on Port 80, so either you have to use reverse proxy or ip tables as sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3001

Comment: I thought security groups was there to help with this kind of scenario. Moreover I am trying to run different nodejs files on different ports and thus let them behave as separate micro services. if I redirect all the requests on port 80 to port 3001, that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @rxysm if you look at the code it is obviously running on port 3001, not port 80. There would be no need for an iptables routing rule here.

Comment: @user3276247 Security groups are not there to help with that kind of scenario. Security groups simply block/allow traffic, they don't forward to different ports. However that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Express to listen to all traffic, not just localhost traffic. Change your `app.listen` line to:

```
app.listen(3001, "0.0.0.0");
```